# WebApi Controller Method with SimpleInjector not adding records to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, simple-injector

On my form I am using ajax to submit the form to my API controller method for creating new objects.  In my API controller, I am using SimpleInjector for Dependency Injection but for some reason when that method is hit, my object isn't being added/saved to the database table.  I am not receiving any runtime errors and it debugs perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
// POST: api/MedicInfoesApi
[ResponseType(typeof(MedicInfo))]
public IHttpActionResult PostMedicInfo(MedicInfo medicInfo)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    // Create empty Employee Object to get info of person being submitted via IBM
    Employee emp = new Employee();

    //check if IBM that user is submitting exists
    if (!EmployeeData.IsValidIBM(medicInfo.MedicIbm))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "This IBM does not exist!");
    }
    // Check if any existing IBM's match what the user is trying to submit... if none then save to database
    else if (_dbContext.GainAccess().MedicInfoes.Any(x => x.MedicIbm.Equals(medicInfo.MedicIbm, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "This person already exists!");
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    else
    {
        // Set empty Employee object with Data of person
        emp = EmployeeData.GetEmployee(medicInfo.MedicIbm);
        medicInfo.Active = true;
        _dbContext.GainAccess().MedicInfoes.Add(medicInfo); // no errors but nothing is added
        _dbContext.GainAccess().SaveChanges(); // no errors but nothing saves
    }

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = medicInfo.Id }, medicInfo);
}
```

Comment: _"my object isn't being added/saved to the database"_ - how do you determine that? Are you looking at the same database as your application writes to?

Comment: @CodeCaster yes I am.  When the method fully executes, I execute the table that this is supposed to write to, and it remains empty.  Plus, on completion of my ajax, it redirects to a page that retrieves all of the objects from that table, and that page is empty

Comment: So what actually is the `GainAccess()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a suspicion that `GainAccess()` may be returning a new instance of your context every time it is called, which could explain the behavior.

```
_dbContext.GainAccess().MedicInfoes.Add(medicInfo); // This instance is never saved
_dbContext.GainAccess().SaveChanges(); // This instance has nothing to save
```

You are calling your Add and Save on completely different instances of your context. So those method calls are independent of each other.

In the first instance you add a record but never save to the database. you then create another new instance and then tell it to save changes, but it has no changes to save because it is a new instance with nothing done to it.

Try using the same instance for the operation.

```
medicInfo.Active = true;
var context = _dbContext.GainAccess(); //what ever it returns.
context.MedicInfoes.Add(medicInfo);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: That worked!  Can you go a little further in explanation?

Comment: @M12Bennett You are calling your Add and Save on completely different instances of your context. So those method calls are independent of each other. In the first instance you add a record but never save to the database. you then create another new instance and then tell it to save changes, but it has no changes to save because it is a new instance with nothing done to it.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you!